# Make Bootstrap static-navbar overlay content like fixed-navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

Using bootstrap 3. I have a full-screen hero/intro section that has a background pattern.

**WHAT I WANT**:

1. A static navbar that overlays this hero section so that the background pattern of the hero section shows in the background of the navbar (like it would if I used "navbar-fixed-top" instead of "navbar-static-top").

What I want it to look like (navbar-fixed-top style):
[image: desired look]

2. When navbar collapses in mobile-view, the hamburger icon shows the navbar links without pushing down the hero section.

[image: desired look]

**WHAT HAPPENS**:

1. Using "static" stacks navbar section before hero section instead of overlaying it
   [image: actual look]
2. Pressing hamburger icon pushes down hero section instead of overlaying it
   [image]

Any idea how I could accomplish this without giving the hero section a negative margin?

My HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main-collapse">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x80" alt=" Logo" width="100">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbar-main-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="..." target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> Link 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<section id="hero" class="full-screen-section">
    <div class="cell-mid">
        <div class="section-body">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 text-right">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x120" id="faceOne" class="img-max hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
                        <h1 class="brand-heading">EXAMPLE HEADING</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 text-left">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x120" id="faceTwo" class="img-max hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

My CSS:

```
/* --------------- Nav --------------- */

.navbar {
    padding: 1em 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
}

.navbar a {
    color:#fff;
}

/* --------------- Hero --------------- */

#hero {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 200px 0 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(
      rgba(248, 153, 153, 0.68), 
      rgba(248, 153, 153, 0.68)), url('bg-science.png');
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

**EDIT**: 
Solution found, thanks to @airbean.  Just used the navbar-fixed-top class and added "position: absolute" on the navbar class.

Comment: absolute/relative positioning?

Comment: @aibrean great, worked! - edited my question

Comment: When in doubt, position LOL.

Comment: Can I suggest you write an answer detailing your solution, rather than putting it in the answer/comments. It makes it easier for potential users with a similar issue to see there's a solution. You also get magical unicorn points (also known as reputation) when people upvote your good answer :)

Comment: Yeah you should write an answer for this and so that it no longer appears unanswered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Aibrean helped out.  I used the navbar-fixed-top class and added "position: absolute" on the navbar class.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old thread but I had the same problem, I positioned the navbar absolutely the links on the right of the navbar become positioned on the left.

Comment: I am sure I can find several equally plausible ways to apply what is stated in the answer. If a corrected version of the code were posted, that would make the answer more usable.